# Improving my rails control flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a really convoluted method defined in my model which I call in my view:

```
  def self.current_rating(recommendation_id, rating_set, product_id)
    if !Recommendation.find(recommendation_id).ratings.find_by_rating_set(rating_set).nil?
      Recommendation.find(recommendation_id).ratings.find_by_rating_set(rating_set).rating.to_i
    elsif  !Recommendation.find(recommendation_id).ratings.find_by_product_id(product_id).nil?
      Recommendation.find(recommendation_id).ratings.find_by_product_id(product_id).rating.to_i
    else
    end
  end
```

and in my view I call:

```
:selected => Rating.current_rating(rec.id,params[:rating_set_id], params[:product_id])
```

in my `select_tag`.

Basically I want to check if anything is returned from the first find, if `nil` check the second find, and if that is `nil` return nothing. How can I refactor this to be better/more syntactic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do various things. Without knowing a whole lot about your application, here is what I would recommend:

Every step of this includes `Recommendation.find(recommendation_id)`, which makes me think you want this to be an instance method on the `Recommendation` model, so you're not potentially running 4 identical recommendation lookups.

The first line of this method gets the rating you want from the recommendation. The `rating` variable remains `nil` unless something is found.

```
def current_rating(rating_set, product_id)
  ratings.find_by_rating_set(rating_set) || ratings.find_by_product_id(product_id)
end
```

So now you're left with a method that either returns a `rating` or `nil`. Since we don't know what you plan to do with this, it's hard to say what you should do next, but I feel this is a better overall strategy for this situation, as this method is clear in its intention, and at least somewhat predictable in its output (I would be a bit alarmed if I called a `current_rating` method and received an integer instead of a Rating object). If are using this to display the rating's number in a view, this is a good candidate for a decorator or some other pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.current_rating(recommendation_id, rating_set, product_id)
    r = Recommendation.find(recommendation_id).ratings
    x = r.find_by_rating_set(rating_set) || r.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    x && x.rating.to_i
end
```

So I notice that all your expressions start with finding a Recommendation based on the reco id, and getting its ratings. So I do that first, assign to `r`.

Then I try to find by rating_set, if that fails (it'll return nil) it short-circuits to finding by product id. If that fails (nil), then x will be nil.

Whether we find by rating_set or product id, either have a rating method. So if x is not nil (x &&) we call rating, and then call to_i. That gets returned as it is the last expression.

If x was nil, the result of (nil && whatever) gets returned, which is nil.